# Why we get at most $N^2$ probe sequences using double hash function

Tags: algorithms, hash, number-theory

**Question**:Given the following double hash function:

$$h(k,i) = (h_1(k) + i\times h_2(k)) \bmod{N}$$, where $h_1(k): key \to \mathbb{Z}$. $h(k,i)$ can generate $N^2$ probe sequences at most and $h_2(k)$ can determine the increment for the probe sequence. Also, $N$ is the number of slots.

**Problem**:Each sequence generated from double hash function regarded as 1 of $N^2$, so my question is why at most we can have $N^2$ probe sequences please? For example, in linear hashing where $h(k,i) = (h_1(k) + i) \bmod{N}$ , we can have N probe sequences at most because for each number $i=0,1, \cdots$ we can get a sequence. Similarly, why we get $N^2$ probe sequences in the double form please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $(h_{1}(k))\mod N$ can take $N$ distinct values and $(h_{2}(k))\mod N$ can take $N$ distinct values. To show that the total number of sequences are $N^2$, we will need to show that for some different inputs $k_1$ and $k_2$, if $(h_{1}(k_{1}) \not\equiv h_{1}(k_2) \mod N)$ or $(h_{2}(k_1) \not\equiv h_2(k_2) \mod N)$, then the probing sequences would be different for $k_1$ and $k_2$. Let the sequence generated by $k_1$ is $P_1$ and the sequence generated by $k_2$ is $P_2$.

**Proof:** Suppose $(h_{1}(k_{1}) \not\equiv h_{1}(k_2) \mod N)$. Then, for $i = 0$, the first element of the $P_1$ would be $h_{1}(k_{1}) \mod N$, and the first element of the $P_2$ would be $h_{1}(k_{2}) \mod N$. Since their first elements are different, the sequences are different.

And, suppose if $(h_{1}(k_{1}) \equiv h_{1}(k_2) \mod N)$ and $(h_{2}(k_{1}) \not\equiv h_{2}(k_2) \mod N)$. Then, for $i = 1$, the second element of $P_1$ would be $(h_{1}(k_{1}) + h_{2}(k_{1})) \mod N$ which is different from the second element of $P_2$, i.e., $(h_{1}(k_{2}) + h_{2}(k_{2})) \mod N$. You can easily prove this statement using contradiction.

---

Note: I noticed later that you are just asking for **at most** $N^2$ sequences. It is actually trivial since $(h_{1}(k)\mod N)$ can take $N$ distinct values and $(h_{2}(k)\mod N)$ can take $N$ distinct values. For a fixed value of $(h_{1}(k)\mod N)$ and $(h_{2}(k)\mod N)$, we have a particular sequence. Therefore, the sequences can be at most $N^2$. But, what I proved earlier is much stronger, i.e., the number of possible sequences could **actually be** $N^2$.

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Thank you very much. @Thank you very much. Are you trying to say in the first line of proof that $h_1(k_1) \ncong h_1(k_2) \bmod{N}$ please? I mean you are saying they are not congruent please? So for two different values, $k_1, k_2$ then $h_1$ does not give same values? So, if that is the case that for different values, hash funtion give different sequences, then for each value in $P_1$, we would give a sequence, in total, we would have $N$ different values for each from first hash function $h_1$ and similarily for $h_2$, which gives in total $N^2$?

Comment: @Avra I mean that $(h_1(k_1) \mod N) \neq (h_1(k_2) \mod N)$. Does that clarify? Maybe I should say $h_1(k_1) \not\equiv h_1(k_2) \mod N$...

Comment: @Avra Yes. For a fixed value of $(h_1 \mod N)$ and $(h_2 \mod N)$, there is one particular sequence. So, in total, we would have $N$ different values for each from first hash function $(h_1 \mod N)$ and similarily for $(h_2 \mod N)$, which gives in total $N^2$ sequences.

Comment: 100% clear answer.

Comment: One last question pleas, so you concluded that the the first element is not same as second based on if $(h_{1}(k_{1}) \equiv h_{1}(k_2) \mod N)$ and $(h_{2}(k_{1}) \not\equiv h_{2}(k_2) \mod N)$. Then, for $i = 1$, because $(h_{1}(k_{1}) + h_{2}(k_{1})) \mod{N} \not \equiv (h_{1}(k_{2}) + h_{2}(k_{2})) \mod{N}$, so you concluded that element in $P_1$ is different from element in $P_2$ please?

Comment: @Avra In case 2, the second element of the two sequences are different. Therefore, the sequences are different. Are you asking for its proof using contradiction?

Comment: We can do it using contrapositive, so I am good at this point thanks.